# Convert scientific notation to number ( dart & flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I convert scientific notation to number in dart ?

```
ex: 9.565108299996563e-10 to 0.0000000009565108299996563

    9.565108299996563e-10 to 0.0000000009565108299996563
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String scientificNotation = "9.565108299996563e-10";
double number = double.parse(scientificNotation);
String formattedNumber = number.toStringAsFixed(20);

print(formattedNumber); // 0.00000000095651083000
```